# Cast Int Array to Enum Flags

Tags: c#

I have the following enum with flags:

```
[Flags]
public enum DataFiat {
  Public = 1,
  Listed = 2,
  Client = 4
} // DataFiat
```

And I have an int array, for example:

```
int[] selected = new int[] { 1, 4 }
```

How can I convert this to my enum which would become:

```
DataFiat.Public | DataFiat.Client
```

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like

```
var tt = (DataFiat)selected.Aggregate((i, t) => i | t);
```

Comment: I think that might be a good solution since it works with new int[] { 1, 3 }; ... Amy I right?

Comment: Yes, I tested and it worked, producing `DataFiat.Public | DataFiat.Listed`

Comment: So help me to understand: why does 1, 3 result in `DataFiat.Public | DataFiat.Listed` ?

Comment: For `{1,3}` the int value of `selected.Aggregate((i, t) => i | t)` is `3` which is equal to `DataFiat.Public | DataFiat.Listed`

Comment: That's right. But If I suppose that 1, 4  means `The Enum flag with value 1 and the Enum flag with value 4` how does 1, 3 fit into this logic?

Comment: @csteinmueller - well, `{1,4}` does not mean `1 *and* 4` it means `1 *or* 4, I don't care exactly which`. `3` in this case means `1 or 2` and so it's easy to see that `{1,3}` turns into `{1,1,2}` which means `1 or 1 or 2` or without redundancy `1 or 2`, in this case `Public` or `Listed`.

Comment: Okay, now I understand :)

Comment: @csteinmueller - Well, I lied a little... if you have `field = 1 | 2;`, then of course, the `field` has both the value of `1` *and* `2`. In bits this is `0001 | 0010 => 0011` which is `3`. The fun thing is, that `1 | 3` or `0011 | 0001` is *still* `3`. These kinds of Flags are basically bitswitches, when the values are powers of 2. Which is, why I prefer to define them like `[Flags]public enum DataFiat { Public = 0x0001, Listed = 0x0010, Client = 0x0100 }` which makes it easier to see, what's happening. :)

Comment: @Corak: I prefer doing it as `0`, `1<<0`, `1<<1`, 1<<2`, `1<<3`, `1<<4`, etc. its more compact and readable (in my view) than a 1 in amongst lots of zeros. For those unaware `<<` is a binary shift operator which basically moves the 1 across by the second number, giving the same sequence that Corak gave. The 0 is used for an explicit `None` value.

Answer (score 6):

```
var f = (DataFiat)selected.Sum();
```

Comment: This is nice and short but only works if the `selected` array doesn't contain duplicates or values that are already the result of an or-operation.

Comment: astanders answer with the aggregate might help (DataFiat)selected.Aggregate((i, t) => i | t);

Answer (score 3):

this snippet:

```
        var intArr = new[] { 1, 4 };
        var sum = intArr.Sum(x => x);
        var result = (Test)sum;
```

returns

[image]

Comment: Sure? I tested it and I get Client ... You should get Public because you have 1 and Public | Listed because you have 3 so in the end you should get Public | Listed ...

Answer (score 2):

```
DataFlat result = (DataFlat) 0;

foreach (var value in selected)
{
    result |= (DataFlat)value;
}
```

Or if you want to use LINQ

```
DataFlat result = (DataFlat) selected.Aggregate(0, (old, current) => old | current);
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can't just cast the array, if it's really an object[]. You can create a new array pretty easily though:**

```
var enumArray = originalArray.Cast<DataFiat>().ToArray();
```

If it were actually an int[] array to start with, you could cast - although you'd have to talk nicely to the C# compiler first:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    enum Foo
    {
        Bar = 1,
        Baz = 2
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        int[] ints = new int[] { 1, 2 };
        Foo[] foos = (Foo[]) (object) ints;
        foreach (var foo in foos)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(foo);
        }
    }
}
```

The C# compiler doesn't believe that there's a conversion from int[] to Foo[] (and there isn't, within the rules of C#)... but the CLR is fine with this conversion, so as long as you can persuade the C# compiler to play along (by casting to object first) it's fine.

**This doesn't work when the original array is really an object[] though.**

Hope this helps..